# How can I install the Conkerer web browser on windows?

Tags: windows, kde, konqueror

I want to use the Conkeror Web Browser on windows. i have installed KDE for windows but I cannot find an installer for Conqueror.

Note: I previously mistakly referred to Conkerer as Konquerer. Thanks Daxim for pointing this out :)

Comment: You did not say for which purpose you need Konqueror. In most use cases, you are better off with a [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webkit)-based browser.

Comment: I need Conkerer as I want keyboard only webbrowsing

Answer (score 1):

- Download the KDE version of andLinux (more than 500MB);
- Install andLinux
- Click the Konqueror icon in the QuickLaunch bar.

From [this blog](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/10/tip-run-kde-konqueror-on-windows-in-three-easy-steps/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work on my 64 bit windows 7. Thanks anyway

Comment: "It does not work" is not a useful problem description for anyone.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant to say that "andLinux" is only available for 32bit Windows systems

Answer (score 0):

I have since found the answer here. DOn't know how I missed it actually??

http://conkeror.org/InstallationWindows

Comment: Downvote: [Conkeror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conkeror) ≠ [Konqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror)

Comment: You are right. I simply thought it was two ways of spelling the same product. Thanks Daxim.